# symbolicatecrash from XCODE 6 GM

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Any one tried symbolicatecrash from XCODE-6 GM release? I am looking for

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

But now it is not available into Xcode-6 package. It was available in Xcode-5

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just went through this moments ago. The `symbolicatecrash` file moved. It's now at:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash

Of course you should adjust the root of this path based on where you installed Xcode 6.

I used the new path to update the soft link in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

This has moved again in Xcode 7.3. It's now at:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash